# Using SDO_Distance to Sort by Distance Between 2 Places

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to find which restaurant is furthest away from the town geometry. Here is the code I have attempted so far:

```
SELECT sort(SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(restaurants.geometry, towns.geometry, 0.005))
FROM restaurants, towns
```

The town is a specific area so I wish to find what restaurant is the furthest away. And then order them if that is possible

Thankyou!

Comment: And what did that query yield?

Comment: Hi! It outputs 1000's of different distances. Probably because the town is represented by a sequence of segments

Answer (score 0):

You could make a ranking over the distances. So first calculate the distances, then apply a ranking over those, and then get only the ones with the highest ranking:

Can all be done in one query with a repeated expression for the distance, but I usually like to break it up in steps using `with`, like so:

```
WITH
  distances AS (
    SELECT
      restaurants.*,
      towns.*,
      SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(restaurants.geometry, towns.geometry, 0.005) AS distance
    FROM 
      restaurants CROSS JOIN towns),

  distance_ranks AS (
    SELECT
      distances.*,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY town_id ORDER BY distance DESC) AS ranking
    FROM
      distances)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  distance_ranks
WHERE
  ranking = 1;
```

I used `dense_rank` here. `rank` would give the same results (since you only get the first one). This may lead to multiple results per town, if they are of equal distance. If you don't want that, you can use `row_number` and apply some extra field to the ordering (for instance restaurant name), to get only one of the two.

Comment: This work! However... It has restaurants listed multiple times with different distances because of how the town is setup. Is there anything that can be done about this? Or maybe just selecting the restaurant that is furthest away?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Keep in mind that I can't see your table structure, let alone the data. This should get the restaurant that is furthest away _per town_. If you don't want it per town, you can change that by removing the `partition by town_id` clause in the ranking.